# Can we use a drone instead of rocket?

Tags: launch, rockets, design-alternative

I would like to know if it is possible to use a drone instead of the rocket to launch a satellite into orbit.

If no, then I would like to know why, and if yes, then in which countries would this be allowed?

Comment: Check out https://what-if.xkcd.com/58/ for an introduction to the basics of getting to orbit (and staying there). Then you can narrow down your question a bit, specifying the general approach you propose and focusing on a particular issue.

Comment: A drone typically uses either wings (MQ-9) or rotors like a helicopter to generate lift (most commercially available consumer models). That is why the question about helicopters answers your question: no we can not.

Comment: @TooTea thanks for the link it's clear my misconception about reaching to space

Comment: Surely most rockets are drones?

Comment: It boils down to this: Drones as we understand them operate in air - they need ambient air to create the thrust that holds them up, and there is no air in space, so they can't get to space. Orbits are very fast; drones as we understand them can't go very fast - maybe a hundred miles per hour; orbital speed is about 17,000 miles per hour. TooTea's xkcd link illustrates the point rather nicely, I think.

Comment: A drone is defined as a remote-controled or pilotless craft or vehicle. Cars, boats, planes, and walking robots can all be drones. All modern rockets except for those that launch humans are drones.

Comment: Well, even rockets that launch humans are for the most part of the flight autonomous drones with humans as cargo.